# Analyticity of this multivariate Laplace transform

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

Consider a $d$-dimensional random vector $\mathbf X$ with laplace transfrom $$L(\mathbf t) = \left(1 + \langle \mathbf \theta, \mathbf t \rangle\right)^{-\alpha}$$

Where $\mathbf \theta$ is a $d$-dimensional vector of non-negatives reals (some can be zero, not all), and $\alpha$ is a strictly positive real (that cannot be zero). The coresponding random vector writes as $\mathbf X = \left(\theta_1 Y,...,\theta_d Y\right)$ for $Y$ a random variable following a gamma distribution with shape $\alpha$ and unit scale, that is with laplace tranform $\left(1 + t\right)^{-\alpha}$. Therefore, $\mathbf X$ is a comonotonous vector, living on a straigth half-line in $\mathbb R^d$.

**Question:** Considering $L$ as a function from $\mathbb C^d$ to $\mathbb C$, what is the region of convergence of $L$ ? Where are it's singularities ?

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha >0$ and
$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^n} e^{-\langle t, x\rangle} d\mu_X(x)= \int_{ \Bbb{R}}e^{-\langle t, \theta y\rangle} d\mu_Y(y)= 
\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-\langle t, \theta \rangle y} \frac{y^{\alpha-1} e^{-y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} dy
 $$ converges for $\Re(\langle \theta,t\rangle) > -1$ and diverges for $\Re(\langle \theta,t\rangle) \le -1$.

It extends analytically to $\{ t\in \Bbb{C}^n,\langle \theta,t\rangle\in U\}$ where $U$ is any simply connected open of $\Bbb{C}-\{-1\}$.

If $\alpha$ is an integer then it extends to a meromorphic function on $\Bbb{C}^n$ with only one pole of order $\alpha$ at the hypersurface $\langle \theta,t\rangle=-1$.

Comment: So, if i get you correctly, this function is analytic on $\Re\left(\langle \mathbf \theta, \mathbf t \rangle\right) > -1$ ? In particular, it's dominant singularity would be at the $\mathbf t$ such that $\langle \mathbf \theta, \mathbf t \rangle = -1$ the closest to the origin ?

Comment: In complex dimension $\ge 2$ the singularities are hypersurfaces, not isolated points.

Comment: Yeah I suck at complex analysis. Once i have the dominant singularity, could you point me in the right direction to obtain asymptotics on the taylor coefficients of the function, like the exponential growth formula in dimension $d=1$ ? Is there some good ref I could read ?

Comment: The Taylor coefficients of what ? Your function reduces to $(1+z)^{-\alpha}= \sum_{k\ge 0} {-\alpha \choose k} z^k$

Comment: I am dealing with a more complicated function (which is closely related to this one) that writes as $g(\mathbf t) = (1 + \mathbf t)^{\mathbf 1}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n L_i(\mathbf t)$ for several $L_i$ that are equal to $L$ but with different parameters each. My goal is to understand asymptotics of the taylor coeffs of this function, which is why i was wandering about the singularities of $L$.